# Passing variable from ajax to php fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am very new to javascript and ajax and I would like to do the folowing:

I have got a page where you can select the name of the person you want to upload a file. Then, through javascript you get that name in a variable and through ajax you pass the variable to a .php file where the upload takes place. The problem is that no name is passed and the file is upload in the same folder where all the names of the people are, not inside one of them. Here is the code I have got for the moment:

**SOME NEW EDITS IN THE CODE**

**html**

```
<select id="cuadro" name="op-cliente">
         <option>bbraun</option>
         <option>biosystems</option>
         <option>seat</option>
         <option>tradsp</option>
         <option>tradin</option>
         <option>vanderlande</option>
   </select>

   <script type="text/javascript">

              $(function() {

              // Setup html5 version
              $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
                // General settings
                runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
                url : 'plupload/examples/upload.php',
                multipart_params: {'valor' : $('#cuadro').val()},
                chunk_size: '5mb',
                rename : true,
                dragdrop: true,    
                filters : {
                // Maximum file size
                max_file_size : '500mb',
                // Specify what files to browse for
                mime_types: [
                ]
                },
                flash_swf_url : 'plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
                silverlight_xap_url : 'plupload/js/Moxie.xap'
                });
              });
            </script>
```

**php**

```
   $valor = $_REQUEST['valor'];
$targetDir = ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $valor;
$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 7 * 24 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds


// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
    @mkdir($targetDir);
}

// Get a file name
if (isset($_REQUEST["name"])) {
    $fileName = $_REQUEST["name"];
} elseif (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
} else {
    $fileName = uniqid("file_");
}

$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

// Chunking might be enabled
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;


// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir) {
    if (!is_dir($targetDir) || !$dir = opendir($targetDir)) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }

    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

        // If temp file is current file proceed to the next
        if ($tmpfilePath == "{$filePath}.part") {
            continue;
        }

        // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
        if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge)) {
            @unlink($tmpfilePath);
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```

**And this last time I got something that could be revealing: if I change this: `multipart_params: {'valor' : $('#cuadro').val()}`, to this: `multipart_params: {'valor' : '5'},` it works and creates a folder called "5"....**

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: What are `comprovations` ?

Comment: It seems you are passing value in url and using post method,  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Sorry Darren, I meant "checkings"

Answer (score 0):

I see you're passing it as a GET value. Therefore the variable is not in the POST.

Change 
`$_POST['valor'];` to `$_GET['valor'];`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! with the GET value it puts the correct file in the same place than before but puts an strange file like "file_56bd9ae967d3e" in the correct folder. Any idea of why it is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the problem i think you face is because you send the name of the person in one request and the file in an other request but if you send them in the same request you will get the wanted result i have tested this and it works for me.

**this is index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('#my_Form').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form=$(this);
        var fd = (window.FormData)? new FormData($form[0]) : null;
        var data=(fd !==null)? fd : $form.serialize(); 

        $.ajax($form.attr('action'),{
            type:$form.attr('method'),
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            dataType:'json',
            data:data,
            success:function(response){alert("sucess");},
            error:function(response){alert("update failre");}

        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="my_Form" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<select name="person" >
<option value="jhon">jhnon</option>
<option value="albert">albert</option>
<option value="achabahe">achabahe</option>
<option value="Tom">Tom</option>
</select>
<input type="file" name="myFile"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**and this is upload.php**

```
<?php
$tempFile=$_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']; 
$targetDir = ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_POST['person'];
$uploadedFileName= $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
$maxFileAge=7*24*3600;
$cleanUpTargetDir=true;

if(!file_exists($targetDir)){
    @mkdir($targetDir); 
}
if($dir=opendir($targetDir)){
while($file=readdir($dir)) {
    $file=$targetDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
    if(filemtime($file)<(time() - $maxFileAge  )){
        @unlink($file);
    }   
}   

}else{
  die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');    
}
$filePath= $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$uploadedFileName;
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$filePath);

?>
```

Comment: Hi @achabahe, thank you for your help. I have tried it but it does not work.

Comment: i have edited this answer it works for me i have tested it

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative

```
<select id="cuadro" name="op-cliente">
     <option>bbraun</option>
     <option>biosystems</option>
     <option>seat</option>
     <option>tradsp</option>
     <option>tradin</option>
     <option>vanderlande</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#cuadro').change(function(){
    var selectedValue = $("#cuadro").val();
    $.ajax({url:"plupload/examples/upload.php?valor="+selectedValue,cache:false,success:function(result){
        alert("success");
    }});
});
</script>
```

**upload.php** (For this way, use `$_GET` to get `valor`.)

```
$targetDir = ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
                "uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_GET['valor'];
```

Comment: Your alternative puts the correct file in the same place than before but puts an strange file like "file_56bd9ae967d3e" in the correct folder.
Any idea of why it is wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi @user3894819: My alternative code has no relation with your file like `file_56bd9ae967d3e`. It's just passing the value using ajax. You have to show your code of file.

Comment: Hi @NanaPartykar, original post edited. I added a function I have below what I had and more code of the .php file. Thank you for your time

Comment: Frankly Speaking, I am not getting why that extra file got added. And, extremely sorry for not being able to solve it. @user3894819

Comment: And, one more thing. Because of my Ajax code your extra file is not getting added. Because, it has no relation with that. There is something else. I am happy to see you used my code there. And, sorry for not solving other problem @user3894819

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to go further, get what fails and post it there

Comment: Hi there @NanaPartykar ! I got something new. Please, have a look :)